# Minecraft won't open

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I saw a post about this from a while ago, and I tried everything they said but nothing helped. My Minecraft on my Toshiba laptop no longer runs, it did around 5 days ago but it just won't work since I last went out of it. When I double click on it, the cursor loads as if it will open, but then won't. I'm getting really frustrated as I have tried basically everything and nothing has done anything. I've deleted it and re-downloaded it various times. I've updated java, I've tried to right click then click open, I tried getting different files for it, I tried shutting off my laptop and restarting in countless times, but nothing is working. I've had the game for just over a week and I'm really disappointed as I just want to play the game. The Mojang website is doing absolutely nothing to help me. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Does it Spawn a Minecraft process in task manager? OS version? What AV do you have and if you disable it does it work?

Comment: Did you try deleting the `runtime` folder in your Minecraft directory (where Minecraft.exe is, not the `.minecraft` folder)?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem and it may be a problem with Minecraft. If you purchased Minecraft [this website](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/topics/420959-minecraft-troubleshooting/articles) might help

Also more of your situation is [This](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/1858086-java-keeps-crashing-minecraft)

This is for un-modified Minecraft. If you modified it you will need to make a copy of your modified version and re-install Minecraft.

Google 'Java Minecraft Fix' and check them out!
Otherwise just google 'Java Download' and click on the first one.
***Sorry for the google searches, the website didn't allow me to add more than 2 links***

It should self override. Otherwise just reset your game. 1.9 snapshots could also cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling Java and reinstalling it.

Java Downloads:
Windows: http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=116039
Mac: http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=116022

Comment: Are you sure that will work?

Comment: Theirs a chance that code work, but I think it more of a Minecraft problem not a Java

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  What I did was hover at the bottom of the screen where it shows that it's on.  Then I go to the picture of the minecraft home screen, right click, and press maximize.  Then press play, and it works!